# JSONField serializes as json for POST, but string for GET

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

There is likely a very simple problem with my code, but I've been slamming my head against this problem for a couple days and can't make any headway.

**Important Packages:**

```
Django==1.11.3
django-cors-headers==2.1.0
djangorestframework==3.7.0
drf-nested-routers==0.90.0
psycopg2==2.7.3
pycparser==2.18
```

Here is what is happening:

I create a model via an AJAX call

[image]

My server correctly serializes the **brainstorm_data** field as a json object.

Now I navigate my user to the next page and fetch the current model

[image]

For some reason, **brainstorm_data** is now be returned as a string. Anytime I call a GET request on this resource I always get a string representation of the JSON object.

Here is the code associated:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Adventure(TimeStampedModel,
                    models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        world = models.ForeignKey(World)
        theme = models.ForeignKey(Theme, default=1)
        brainstorm_data = JSONField()
        image_src = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
        sentence_summary = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        paragraph_summary = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        page_summary = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
        outline_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        brainstorm_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        private = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
class MyAdventuresViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Adventure.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AdventureSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Adventure.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        world = World.objects.filter(user=user).first()

        if not world:
            world = World.objects.create(name='My World', user=user,
                                         description="This is a default world we created for your adventures",
                                         image_src=static('worlds/images/world_placeholder.png'))

        data = request.data.copy()
        data['user'] = user.pk
        data['world'] = world.pk
        data['theme'] = 1  # default theme
        data['brainstorm_data'] = default_brainstorm
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        adventure = serializer.save()

        Storyboard.objects.create(adventure=adventure, raw=default_storyboard['raw'], html=default_storyboard['html'])

        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def complete_outline(self, request, pk):
        adventure = Adventure.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        complete_adventure_outline(adventure)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=adventure)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=200)

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def genres(self, request, pk):
        genre_names = request.data
        genre_models = Genre.objects.filter(name__in=genre_names)
        adventure = self.get_object()
        adventure.genre_set.set(genre_models)
        adventure.save()
        serializer = AdventureSerializer(adventure)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AdventureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    genre_set = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    character_set = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    location_set = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    storyboard = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    theme = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Theme.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Adventure
        fields = '__all__'
```

**mixins**

```
# this is a dictionary used to default brainstorm data each time an adventure is created
default_brainstorm = {
    "nodes": [...],
    "edges": [...]
}
```

Comment: I think my problem stems from the underlying database column being 'text' as opposed to 'jsonb'. When I created a new class "ABC" and migrated a JSONField it would be a 'jsonb' column, but when I compare that to my previous columns they are 'text'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the `to_internal_value` and `to_representation` in a new serializer field to handle the return data for JSON field.

```
class JSONSerializerField(serializers.Field):
    """Serializer for JSONField -- required to make field writable"""

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value
```

And in turn, you would use this Field in a serializer:

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    json_field = JSONSerializerField()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModelClass
        fields = ('json_field', )
```

This should solve your problem :)

Comment: Yes, that would have solved my problem, but I have found the root cause of the issue. When I originally created the columns I did it with a different json field package. The base DB columns with actually **text** instead of **json**. Creating new columns, migrating the data, and then shifting the data back got my database back in a consistent order.

Comment: Awesome, good to hear. I had similar problem with JSON field with MySQL, had use other packages and "hack" it together

Answer (score 0):

When I originally created the columns I did it with a different json field package. The base DB columns was actually **text** instead of **json** or **jsonb**. Creating new columns (django json fields), migrating the data, and then shifting the data back got my database back in a consistent order.